# How to select profiles in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application files according to my environment: `application.yml` and `application-uat.yml`. I'm running the application by providing the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` as environment variable so that the correct file is selected. I have a problem with defining additional profiles inside application.

Suppose I have a bean with profile `mock-rest` that mocks the rest client and I have a bean with profile `actual-rest`.

I've tried two do it in those ways:

```
#inside application.yml
spring:
  profiles:
     include: mock-rest
```

And for `UAT`:

```
#inside application-uat.yml
spring:
  profiles:
     include: actual-rest
```

But the problem is that spring will include both profiles, because it takes the both files and only replaces the values from `uat` yml file.

If I try to use `spring.profiles.active` inside `yml` files Spring will ignore that as the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable will have priority.

So, the question is what is the way to overcome described problem? Basically, I need to define profiles inside `application.yml` files and I want to only define environment as my `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env variable. Is this possible? If not, what are my options to consider?

Comment: What is the second profile? From your example I only see the 'uat' profile. Keep in mind application.yml will always be loaded as this is the default configuration file. Spring should override the values defined there from the file application-uat.yml (if the active profile is set to 'uat')

Comment: @GerbenJongerius that exactly the problem. If I put `spring.profiles.include` in both files specifying in one `mock-rest` and the `actual-rest` in the other - then it will include both `mock-rest` and `actual-rest` and enable them both in application on `uat` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `application.yml` file is read whatsoever. This is an indented behaviour. Usually, all values in `application.yml` would be overrided by other more specific `application-*.yml`.
But profiles are not a single values, you can have multiple one enabled at the same time, so i does not oeverride the profile, instead it cumulate both.

If you want to get rid of the `mock-rest` on prod environment you might want to remove the `mock-rest` profile from `application.yml` and move it to a new `application-mock.yml` that you can activate using an environment variable.

application.yml

```
# some default configuration
```

application-mock.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
     include: actual-rest
```

application-uat.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
     include: actual-rest
```

Comment: The problem with such approach is that if I want to run application locally from IDE then I need to now to activate the correct profiles every time otherwise it will just fail complaining that it doesn't have required bean. Also what if I will have more profiles? Should I create application file for each of them? What I want is to have the default ones but also the possibility to override them (if it's possible).

Comment: You won't be able to remove/override a profile added in the `application.yml` file. It will stack with other profiles. The best you can do is introduce some shenanigans to force spring understand that if the actual-rest is present it wins the fight (by introduction Conditional on each of your beans). But it will be a pain in the ass to maintain because someday you will forget this anotation and it will turns into a mess, because one of your bean is going to be a mocked one with no explicit error (in prod invironment).

Comment: I rather have an application that fails due to the lack of proper profile (which i can add to the IDE) rather than an non-failure that does not works as intended